# Can you create an event with Webform-CiviCRM integration?

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm, civicrm-entity

I know you can *register* for an event - but can you create an event?

In my use case, there are users whose job is to coordinate an event series who don't otherwise need to interact with CiviCRM.  It would be great to allow them to create events without interacting with the Civi UI.

Answer (score 5):

I know! The answer is CiviCRM Entity! I've done things like: `civicrm-event/9/edit` and `civicrm-contribution/add` -> let's try `civicrm-event/add` - voila:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also use webform + CiviCRM Entity + rules + webform rules to do this job. You would need to gather all required fields for the event on the webform, and map the submitted values properties and use a create entity action

Comment: ooh...this is a very cool option.  Thank you @jackrabbithanna!

Comment: have either of you (or anyone else) done this with D9?

Answer (score 2):

No.

IIRC Xavier was working on something like that at one point. But I don't know the status of that project.